# Converting SQL to QueryOver for getting a row count with group bys

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, nhibernate

I have the following NHibernate QueryOver query:

```
var query = session.QueryOver<IssuanceReportLogEntity>()
                        .Where(i => i.CustomerId == customer.Id && i.RollbackIssuanceId == null);

if (Parms.StartDate != null) query.Where(i => i.IssuanceDateCreated >= Parms.StartDate);
if (Parms.EndDate != null) query.Where(i => i.IssuanceDateCreated <= Parms.EndDate);
if (Parms.GroupId != null) query.Where(i => i.RecipientGroupId == Parms.GroupId);
if (Parms.ProgramId != null) query.Where(i => i.ProgramId == Parms.ProgramId);

query.Select(
    Projections.Group<IssuanceReportLogEntity>(x => x.RecipientGroupId).WithAlias(() => receiver.RecipientGroupId),
    Projections.Group<IssuanceReportLogEntity>(x => x.RecipientId).WithAlias(() => receiver.RecipientId),
    Projections.Group<IssuanceReportLogEntity>(x => x.RecipientFullName).WithAlias(() => receiver.RecipientFullName),
    Projections.Group<IssuanceReportLogEntity>(x => x.RecipientEmployeeNumber).WithAlias(() => receiver.RecipientEmployeeNumber),
    Projections.Group<IssuanceReportLogEntity>(x => x.RecipientTitle).WithAlias(() => receiver.RecipientTitle),
    Projections.Count<IssuanceReportLogEntity>(x=>x.RecipientGroupId).WithAlias(()=>receiver.RecognitionTotalReceived),
    Projections.Sum<IssuanceReportLogEntity>(x=>x.Points).WithAlias(()=>receiver.TotalPoints));

if (customer.Settings.PointsEnabled)
{
    query.OrderBy(Projections.Sum<IssuanceReportLogEntity>(x => x.Points)).Desc();
}
else
{
    query.OrderBy(Projections.Count<IssuanceReportLogEntity>(x => x.InitiatorId)).Desc();
}

query.TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<TopReceiver>());
```

This generates the following query (which is correct for the selection of data):

```
SELECT TOP (20 /* @p0 */) this_.RecipientGroupId        as y0_,
               this_.RecipientId             as y1_,
               this_.RecipientFullName       as y2_,
               this_.RecipientEmployeeNumber as y3_,
               this_.RecipientTitle          as y4_,
               count(this_.RecipientGroupId) as y5_,
               sum(this_.Points)             as y6_
FROM   [IssuanceReportLog] this_
WHERE  (this_.CustomerId = '30a678bc-264a-4a04-aac4-a3270158929f' /* @p1 */
      and this_.RollbackIssuanceId is null)
     and this_.RecipientGroupId = '2fd9ec20-e870-42f6-b345-a3270158992a' /* @p2 */
GROUP  BY this_.RecipientGroupId,
        this_.RecipientId,
        this_.RecipientFullName,
        this_.RecipientEmployeeNumber,
        this_.RecipientTitle
ORDER  BY sum(this_.Points) desc
```

What I need to do is to figure out how to get NHibernate to generate a row count WITHOUT ripping out the Group By, essentially to do something like (notice the previous query is essentially a subquery without the TOP):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
SELECT this_.RecipientGroupId        as y0_,
                 this_.RecipientId             as y1_,
                 this_.RecipientFullName       as y2_,
                 this_.RecipientEmployeeNumber as y3_,
                 this_.RecipientTitle          as y4_,
                 count(this_.RecipientGroupId) as y5_,
                 sum(this_.Points)             as y6_
FROM   [IssuanceReportLog] this_
WHERE  (this_.CustomerId = '30a678bc-264a-4a04-aac4-a3270158929f' /* @p1 */
        and this_.RollbackIssuanceId is null)
       and this_.RecipientGroupId = '2fd9ec20-e870-42f6-b345-a3270158992a' /* @p2 */
GROUP  BY this_.RecipientGroupId,
          this_.RecipientId,
          this_.RecipientFullName,
          this_.RecipientEmployeeNumber,
          this_.RecipientTitle
) AS Query
```

Every time I try to get a rowcount to work, NH rips out the GROUP BY. The above SQL works as I expect it to.

Any ideas on how to get NHibernate to spit out that SQL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "standard" way in NHibernate, is to create a clone query:

```
var rowCountQuery = query.ToRowCountQuery();
```

Which does (from docs):

> Clones the `QueryOver`, removes orders and paging, and projects the row-countfor the query

But as you've *(for sure)* already experienced here... that would result in pure query *(because all essential was removed, see the query below)* - returning **wrong result**

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM   [IssuanceReportLog] -- notwhat needed
```

#### The SOLUTION:

Inject the ***magical* sql** snippet into projection:

> **`COUNT(*) OVER() AS TotalRowCount`**

This will return exactly what we need. The total row count `over` our query. We have to extend the DTO:

```
public class TopReceiver
{
    ...
    public virtual int TotalRowCount { get; set; }
```

And adjust the projection like this

```
query.Select(
    ... // all the GROUP BY statements
    // the total row count
    Projections.SqlProjection(" COUNT(*) OVER() AS TotalRowCount "
                   , new string[] { "TotalRowCount" }
                   , new IType[] { NHibernateUtil.Int32 })
    // count, sum
    Projections.Count<IssuanceReportLogEntity>(x=>x.RecipientGroupId)
               .WithAlias(()=>receiver.RecognitionTotalReceived),
    Projections.Sum<IssuanceReportLogEntity>(x=>x.Points)
               .WithAlias(()=>receiver.TotalPoints)
);
```

later we can even apply paging, but the value of `TotalRowCount` will still be correct.

```
query
    .Skip(100)
    .Take(25)
```

And now, each (including the first) result has the info about the total row count.

```
var rowCount = list[0].TotalRowCount;
```

NOTE: Do you know what? **This is in fact the most efficient** way how to get `row-count`. Not only in **one** server-db round trip, but even in **one** sql statement execution...

Comment: That worked like a champ! I saw this technique with HQL but not with QueryOver.

Comment: Great to see that ;) Enjoy NHibernate